# Add multiple elements into all arrays that are equal

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

```
$ node
> A = [0, 1, 23]
[ 0, 1, 23 ]
> B = A
[ 0, 1, 23 ]
> A.splice(0, 3)
[ 0, 1, 23 ]
> B
[]
> A
[]
> A = A.concat([1, 2])
[ 1, 2 ]
> B
[]
```

This is correct. But, is it possible that after calling `concat`, `B` array be equal with `A`?

I know that there is the loop solution, but what other alternatives are there to add multiple elements in multiple arrays that are equal?

BTW, I don't want to modify `B` directly (`A = B = A.concat(...)`).

Comment: Why do you even need such a thing?

Comment: @thefourtheye `1.js` exports an object that contains an array that is used in the module. `2.js` wants to modify that array so `1.js` will use `2.js` data. This is my case.

Comment: if `A` and `B` refer to the same array, then `A.push(element)` will also show up in `B`.

Comment: @Paul Exactly. But I want to insert multiple elements. `A = A.contact(...)` doesn't work because the reference will be changed. `A.push(...);A.push(...);A.push(...)...` will change `B` as well, but the code will not be the best I guess.

Comment: @ionica see Benjamin's answer.  For adding multiple eleemnts, [Function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is a good helper to use with [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: @Paul You're right! I knew that there should be a shorter solution. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paul is correct, you could do:

```
A.push.apply(A,[1, 2]);
```

For those of you not aware, [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) accept variable arguments, and [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) converts a variable arguments accepting function to an array accepting function.

Comment: Oh, what a good idea!

Comment: It's also considerably faster than the alternatives, with the exception being an inline for loop - which is why you see this trick often used with the `arguments` object over .slice or .splice in performance sensitive code (again, an inline for loop is even faster)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.splice` itself, like this

```
var A = [0, 1, 23], B = A;
A.splice.apply(A, [A.length, 0].concat([1, 2]));
console.log(A, B, A === B);
// [ 0, 1, 23, 1, 2 ] [ 0, 1, 23, 1, 2 ] true
```

Here, `A.length` and `0` represent the starting position at the array and number of elements to remove respectively.

We concatenate that with the actual array of elements to be inserted. So, the arguments being passed to `A.splice` would look like this

```
A.splice(A.length, 0, 1, 2);
```

As `splice` does in-place operation, `A` and `B` still refer the same object.